# Babylon.d.ts compiled with gulp console errors

Tags: console, gulp, babylonjs

I am new to typescript and babylon.js. I downloaded the source code for
the book Babylon essentials. I have a gulp file that compiles the babylon.d.ts
library

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');

var files = [
"**.d.ts"
];

gulp.task("default", function() {
var result = gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(ts({ // Transcompile
        out: "compile.js" // Merge into one output file
    }));
return result.js.pipe(gulp.dest("./")); // output file destination
});

// Automatically call the "default" task when a TS file changes
gulp.task("watch", function() {
gulp.watch(files, ["default"]);
});
```

When I compile the library using the command gulp I get 10 console errors
that say: All declarations of "error-name" must have identical modifiers.

my file structure is

```
-project
 -node_modules
 -gulpfile.js
 -appcompiled.js (empty)
 -app.ts (empty)
 -babylon.d.ts
 -babylon.max.js
 -index.html
 -package.json (the dep. are gulp, gulp-typescript, typescript)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The code examples in the book **babylon essentials** SUCK. If someone else has this problem download the babylon.d.ts library off of git hub yourself. It will solve this problem.